# Ruby split with regex - regex isn't doing what i want

Tags: ruby, regex

i have this string

```
string = "<p>para1</p><p>para2</p><p>para3</p>"
```

I want to split on the para2 text, so that i get this

```
["<p>para1</p>", "<p>para3</p>"]
```

The catch is that sometimes para2 might not be wrapped in p tags (and there might be optional spaces outside the p and inside it).  I thought that this would do it:

```
string.split(/\s*(<p>)?\s*para2\s*(<\/p>)?\s*/)
```

but, i get this:

```
["<p>para1</p>", "<p>", "</p>", "<p>para3</p>"]
```

it's not pulling the start and end p tags into the matching pattern - they should be eliminated as part of the split.  Ruby's regular expressions are greedy by default so i thought that they would get pulled in.  And, this seems to be confirmed if i do a gsub instead of a split:

```
string.gsub(/\s*(<p>)?\s*para2\s*(<\/p>)?\s*/, "XXX")
=> "<p>para1</p>XXX<p>para3</p>"
```

They *are* being pulled in and got rid of here, but not on the split.  Any ideas anyone?

thanks, max

Comment: Remember, you can never truly parse HTML with regex. If this string is in any way dependent on outside input, use an HTML parser like hpricot or nokogiri.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your capturing groups `(…)` with non-capturing groups `(?:…)`:

```
/\s*(?:<p>)?\s*para2\s*(?:<\/p>)?\s*/
```

Comment: This answer is correct. When you split by a regex with capturing groups, it puts the captures into the array, so you can do more complex scanning/splitting operations.

Comment: Nifty...didn't know we had that in Ruby!

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, that does the trick.  I'd never even heard of non-capturing groups before, that's a really useful bit of knowledge.