# How to split a string containing both delimiter and the escaped delimiter?

Tags: ruby, regex

My string delimiter is `;`. Delimiter is escaped in the string as `\;`. E.g.,

```
irb(main):018:0> s = "a;b;;d\\;e"
=> "a;b;;d\\;e"
irb(main):019:0> s.split(';')
=> ["a", "b", "", "d\\", "e"]
```

Could someone suggest me regex so the output of split would be `["a", "b", "", "d\\;e"]`? I'm using Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: I think you can do it with a regex. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164211/ruby-split-with-regex-regex-isnt-doing-what-i-want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.8.7 doesn't have negative lookbehind without Oniguruma (which may be compiled in).

1.9.3; yay:

```
> s = "a;b;c\\;d"
=> "a;b;c\\;d"
> s.split /(?<!\\);/
=> ["a", "b", "c\\;d"]
```

1.8.7 with Oniguruma doesn't offer a trivial split, but you *can* get match offsets and pull apart the substrings that way. I assume there's a better way to do this I'm not remembering:

```
> require 'oniguruma'
> re = Oniguruma::ORegexp.new "(?<!\\\\);"
> s = "hello;there\\;nope;yestho"
> re.match_all s
=> [#<MatchData ";">, #<MatchData ";">]
> mds = re.match_all s
=> [#<MatchData ";">, #<MatchData ";">]
> mds.collect {|md| md.offset}
=> [[5, 6], [17, 18]]
```

Other options include:

- Splitting on `;` and post-processing the results looking for trailing `\\`, or
- Do a char-by-char loop and maintain some simple state and just split manually.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, we don't already use Oniguruma gem with Ruby 1.8.7. I was going to try the other options you suggested but dbenhur's solution works for me right now.

Comment: I implemented my own split using a char-by-char loop (your second suggestion). This works even when there are empty fields.

Comment: @svhyd I'm not sure `scan` can't handle that scenario as well, although I'm not familiar enough with it to know how. This is one of those cases, though, where if you don't have proper regex support, doing it "by hand" is IMO acceptable, because your need is pretty narrow. I'm not sure which would be faster, either; depends on how the regex engine is implemented in 1.8.7--if it's Ruby then scanning by hand is likely faster. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

As @dave-newton answered, you could use negative lookbehind, but that isn't supported in 1.8.  An alternative that will work in both 1.8 and 1.9, is to use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) instead of split, with a pattern accepting not (semicolon or backslash) or anychar prefixed by backlash:

```
$ irb
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
>> s = "a;b;c\\;d"
=> "a;b;c\\;d"
s.scan /(?:[^;\\]|\\.)+/
=> ["a", "b", "c\\;d"]
```

Comment: Actually, if there is an empty `;` by itself for a field `scan`  doesn't return an empty String so I lose the positional information of the field. E.g., if the original String were `a;;c\\;d`, your solution returns `["a", "c\\;d"]`. Is there a way to split/scan where the result would be `["a", "", "c\\;d"]`?

Comment: I modified the question to include an empty field (i.e., a semicolon by itself).