# Array length not getting correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in `view.html.erb` page I have code like:

```
<%
 str="D:\\projects\\curator\\java\\hpc"  
 no=str.count("\\")  
 splitstr=str.split(pattern="\\",no+1) 

%>
```

After this I printed

```
<%= splitstr.length %>
```

It gives me the output as `9`. But the `splitstr` has only `5` elements.
How is it happening.

Comment: You end up having four of "" strings in your array. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164236/how-to-split-a-string-containing-both-delimiter-and-the-escaped-delimiter

Comment: just tried this out and I got 5 https://gist.github.com/jvnill/5063030

Comment: @Fdr : Thanks.. that link help me to find out the issue. I got a solution now.

Comment: @яєηנιтн.я Sure, glad it helped. I edited it to an answer, so you can accept that for quicker lookup for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You end up having four of ""(empty) strings in your array

Answer (score 0):

use this instead..

```
 splitstr=str.split("\\")
 splitstr.length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3p385 :007 > str="D:\\projects\\curator\\java\\hpc"  
 => "D:\\projects\\curator\\java\\hpc" 
1.9.3p385 :008 > no=str.count("\\")
 => 4 
1.9.3p385 :009 >  splitstr=str.split(pattern="\\",no+1) 
 => ["D:", "projects", "curator", "java", "hpc"] 
1.9.3p385 :010 > splitstr.length
 => 5 
1.9.3p385 :011 >
```

Im getting it right!